# Updating Multiple Tables in MS Access 2007 Database using c#

Tags: ms-access-2007

I'm totally new in C# programming. I've just jumped into learning it with a windows form application project for managing an inventory system.

I want to update my "Purchase list" and "Balance sheet" to show the current amount of products in my inventory. I am using Access 2007. Need some help here.

At the moment I have only three tables.
1.ItemInformation(ID, ItemCode, ItemName, GroupName, CompanyName, PurchasePrice, ItemUnit, Saleprice, SelfNumber)

2.PurchaseInformation(ID, ItemCode, ItemName, GroupName, CompanyName, PurchasePrice, PurchaseQuantity, TotalPrice, PurchaseDate, Remarks, ItemUnit, SelfNumber)

3.PurchaseInformation(ID, ItemCode, ItemName, GroupName, CompanyName, AvailableQuantity, ItemUnit, SelfNumber)

***ID*** is the ***primary key*** but ***ItemCode is the unique key and the tables are connected using it***.

There will be another table "SalesInformation" showing how many items are sold out. I'll have to update the balance sheet accordingly.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I need the query to join these two tables and to update both table using a single button.

Comment: You should read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here on SO. That will help you write better questions and receive answers. Regarding your question, your tables are poorly designed, and I _strongly_ suggest you read about **RDBMS design** (Google it)